# Configuring pom.xml to push to AWS ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, maven, pom.xml, maven-release-plugin, amazon-ecr

I need to setup pom.xml of my project that can push snapshot build images to the 'mutable enabled' ecr repo in AWS and once the maven release plugin is used the released image to be pushed to the 'immutable enabled' ecr repo.
Currently, I have it configured to just one ecr repo. But the separate push needs to be configured for obvious reasons to not have the release images go to the mutable enabled.

I tried to go through maven release plugin docs, but I don;t see how two repositories (mutable enabled and immutable enabled)can be configured in the same pom.

Any pointers and help welcome.

Thanks